# How to enrich Reactor's Context with data from Mono?

Tags: java, project-reactor

There is a possibility to enrich Reactor's sequence context with some data at subscription time as follows:

```java
Mono.just("Hello")
    .flatMap(s -> Mono.deferContextual(ctx -> Mono.just(s + " " + ctx.get(key)))) 
    .contextWrite(ctx -> ctx.put(key, "World"));
```

However, this `"World"` here is sort of static data which is know at subscription time.

I'd like to resolve a value from the initial Mono itself and put it into the context, so that downstream operators can access it via context API.

How can I properly do that?

The use case I am working on is following:

- I receive an SQS message from AWS via the async SDK which is resolved to a Reactor's Mono
- A message has a `correlation_id` inside which I want to extract and put it into Reactors context to make it visible to all downstream operators.

Answer (score 7):

For now, the only option  to enrich Reactor's context with data from the initial Mono I have found
is to wrap all processing into a `flatMap` with `Mono.deferContextual()...contextWrite()` inside as following:

```java
Mono.just("test")
        .flatMap(s ->
                Mono.deferContextual(ctx -> {
                    System.out.println("key1=" + ctx.getOrEmpty("key")); // Context in place
                    return Mono.just(s);
                }).contextWrite(ctx -> ctx.put("key", s)))
        .flatMap(s -> Mono.deferContextual(ctx -> {
            System.out.println("key2=" + ctx.getOrEmpty("key")); // No Context
            return Mono.just(s);
        }));
```

I hope someone suggests a better solution.

Comment: Are you sure want to use context API? You can use Map (Mono.just(Map.of("key", "test", "data", "some other useful data"))) to pass data from upstream to downstream instead of Mono.just("test").